# factory В AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть фабрика

```
appModule.factory('search', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            getObj: function(url, termParam, entity, array, checkParam) {
                $http.jsonp(url, {
                    params: {
                        "callback": "JSON_CALLBACK",
                        "term": termParam,
                        "limit": 25,
                        "entity": entity
                    }
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    array = data.results;
                    if (array.length == 0) {
                        checkParam = false;
                    } else {
                        checkParam = true;
                    }
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("error" + data);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

и вызов фабрики

```
itunesSearch.getObj("http://itunes.apple.com/search", $scope.searchParam, "musicVideo", $scope.videoArray, $scope.videoCheck);
```

Не могу понять, почему параметры:

 $scope.videoArray
$scope.videoCheck
возвращают undefind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В яваскрипте все параметры передаются по ссылке, поэтому **нельзя** присвоить значение параметру и ожидать, что поменяется переменная снаружи.

Это происходит потому, что параметр просто начинает ссылаться на новый объект внутри функции.

Для решения нужно либо возвращать необходимые объекты:

```
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    return {array:data.results, checkParam:data.results.length != 0};
})
```

И далее в коде:

```
itunesSearch.getObj("http://itunes.apple.com/search", $scope.searchParam, "musicVideo").then(data=>{
    $scope.videoArray=data.array;
    $scope.videoCheck=data.checkParam;
});
```

Либо передавать в функцию объект, и менять у него значения полей. Но так как функция асинхронная - значения изменятся только после получения ответа.

---

Для того, чтобы узнать как получить значения из асинхронных функций можно обратиться к следующему вопросу:

> [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0)